# Use FileSystemWatcher on a single file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

When I try to set the watcher path to a single file like so:

```
watcher.Path = filePath1;
```

I get the error:

> The directory name C:\Cromos 3.0\repository\diagnostics\dwm01_2011_06_13__09_03.LXD is invalid.

Can you only set the path to a folder directory?

Comment: watcher.Filter will do what you need.

Comment: @Charleh, I am not sure I agree with that, as FileSystemWatcher also provides a changed event, so you might want to know when a specific file is changed.

Comment: Ok that's true, it's been a while since I've used it - I'm pretty sure I've read that sometimes it can be unreliable when large numbers of changes/files were added/removed etc

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Your error is setting the Path property with a full filename

```
watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath1); 
watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(filePath1);
```

should work.

Not related to your proper question, but, of course, to enable the FileSystemWatcher's functionality, it is imperative to set the *EnableRaisingEvents* property to true.

Comment: makes sense but the 'OnChanged' event isn't being called when I change the file contents. Is it a problem that my filesystemwatcher is inside a class and not 'Form1'?

Comment: You would have to have an instance of that class running, otherwise there will be no filewatcher.

Comment: Also note that you need to set `EnableRaisingEvents = true` after setting everything else, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but you can watch for specific files by setting the filter property to the filename.

e.g.

```
watcher.Filter = "dwm01_2011_06_13__09_03.LXD";
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this will work if I want to watch multiple single pages. i.e. My filesystemwatcher is inside a 'Page' class. Multiple instances of the class = multiple single pages being watched?

Comment: Perhaps, if static. A Page object will unload after it ends its response.