# How do I keep a RichTextBox updated constantly with a TXT file?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, filesystemwatcher

I have this code, which should keep *richTextBox2* updated at all times with *usedPath*'s contents, but it doesn't.

```
 private void watch()
    {
        var usedPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "usedwords.txt");

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = usedPath;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string usedPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "usedwords.txt");
        richTextBox2.LoadFile(usedPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out what I have wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: Your watcher.Path = path of a single file, which will cause error.

Solution: Look at this: [Use FileSystemWatcher on a single file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798197/use-filesystemwatcher-on-a-single-file-in-c-sharp)

```
watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath1); 
watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(filePath1);
```

Problem 2: Accessing `richTextBox2` in `OnChanged()` will cause cross-thread error

Solution: Use this:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
          string usedPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "usedwords.txt");
          richTextBox2.LoadFile(usedPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);      
    });
}
```

Problem 3: There may be error when trying to LoadFile while some other programs are writing to it.

(Possible) Solution: Put a `Thread.Sleep(10)` in before trying to `LoadFile` in `OnChanged`

```
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(usedPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        });
    }
```

My complete code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string usedPath = @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\usedwords.txt";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        watch();
    }

    private void watch()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(usedPath);
        watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(usedPath);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(usedPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the modifications you talked about, although it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I just added a 3rd possible problem. May I know what error are you getting?

Comment: I am editing and saving usedwords.txt on Notepad, it is updating on richTextBox successfully