# FileSystemWatcher performance

Tags: c#, windows

I need to fire an event when certain file is created. But this file is created in Temp folder inside a directory that is created with it. So I will have to set up monitoring of whole Temp dir with all subdirectories and I'm concerned about performance impact.

I know exact name and path of file and need to only track its creation. Is it better to poll `File.Exists` once a second or set up a `FileSystemWatcher`? Maybe there is a way to disable monitoring of all events except file creation and maybe it will be faster than polling?

I can't really test it because usage pattern of Temp directory is quite unpredictable.

Comment: `I can't really test it because usage pattern of Temp directory is quite unpredictable.` If this were true,then no code using multiple tasks/threads could be tested....

Answer (score 1):

I dont get it. Why you have to set "watch" the whole temp dir? And not just the folder where that file is?

> I know exact name and path of file

BIT OF GOOGLE: [Use FileSystemWatcher on a single file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798197/use-filesystemwatcher-on-a-single-file-in-c-sharp)

This is going to have probably better performance than polling every x ammount of time.

But still, i have read and even happened to me, FSW is not 100% reliable.

So i would think of two approaches:

1) Do a mix of FSW, Poll and user intervention (ie, refresh button)

2) Get some fine drugs and read this: **System Minifilter Driver**
<strike>https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx</strike>

EDIT: new link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/filter-manager-concepts
And a nice code sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/change

Comment: Because the path to it does not exist when program starts. At some point a directory inside Temp will be created. After some time one more dir inside it. Then after some time target file will appear.

Comment: If you know when it will appear, then you can do #1, even knowing that FSW is not so reliable.

Comment: @JuanCarlos the link for the 2nd point is unfortunately broken.

Comment: Oh hello @JuanCarlos! Didn't expect to see you here :D

Comment: Hey @MuhammadAzeez I'm famous xD